# Stopping a function to run more than once in a period of time

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I have this MouseEvent function that I have totally no idea why it fired twice. Is there a way I can disable the function in a period of time? I tried disabling the button, but seems like it directly called the function and does not trigger from the button.

Addition info:When I add in more object to the array, the function fired more time

The Class the handles the button

```
 package classes
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    import classes.playVideo;
    import classes.playList;
    import classes.viewType;

    public class controlMenu extends MovieClip
    {
        private var playV:playVideo=new playVideo();
        private var list:playList=new playList();
        private var viewT:viewType = new viewType();

        private static var con:controls = new controls();

        private static var _buttonStatus:Boolean;

        public function controlMenu()
        {
        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------------

        public function loadControlMenu():void
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,add2Stage);
        }

        private function add2Stage(e:Event):void
        {
            if (stage.numChildren == 1)
            {
                con.x=(stage.stageWidth-230)/2;
                con.y=stage.stageHeight-(con.height+9);
                addChild(con);

                playButtonStatus();

                con.soundBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, soundOver);
                con.soundBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, soundOut);
                con.soundBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, soundDown);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, soundUp);

                con.prev.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,prevClick);
                con.next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nextClick);
            }
        }

        private function playClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (e.currentTarget.currentFrameLabel == "play" && playV.currentVideoStatus == "play")
            {
                e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("pause");
                playV.pauseStatus();
            }
            else if (e.currentTarget.currentFrameLabel=="pause" && playV.currentVideoStatus == "pause")
            {
                e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("play");
                playV.playStatus();
            }
            else if (e.currentTarget.currentFrameLabel == "play"&& playV.currentVideoStatus == "end")
            {
                playV.newVideo = "video/video" + list.currentIndex + ".flv";
            }
        }

        private function playOver(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.currentTarget.btn.gotoAndStop("over");
        }

        private function playOut(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.currentTarget.btn.gotoAndStop("out");
        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------------

        private function soundOver(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("over");
        }

        private function soundOut(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (e.buttonDown == false)
            {
                e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("out");
            }
        }

        private function soundDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var volumeBound:Rectangle = new Rectangle(-93,35,80,0);
            e.currentTarget.startDrag(false, volumeBound);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,soundAdjust);
        }

        private function soundUp(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            con.soundBtn.stopDrag();
            con.soundBtn.gotoAndStop("out");

            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,soundAdjust);
        }

        private function soundAdjust(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            playV.adjustSound = ((con.soundBtn.x+93)*100)/80;
        }

        public function set adjustSoundBtnPos(a:Number):void
        {
            var newPos:Number = ((80*a)/100);
            con.soundBtn.x = newPos - 93;
        }

        private function prevClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (viewT.viewIn == "stream" && list.currentIndex > 1)
            {
                var goBack = list.currentIndex - 1;
                list.currentIndex = goBack;
                playV.newVideo = "video/video" + goBack + ".flv";
                list.currentVideoLink = goBack;
            }
        }

        private function nextClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (viewT.viewIn == "stream" && list.currentIndex < list.vDataLength)
            {
                var goNext = list.currentIndex + 1;
                list.currentIndex = goNext;
                playV.newVideo = "video/video" + goNext + ".flv";
                list.currentVideoLink = goNext;
            }
        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------------

        public function get currentStatus():String
        {
            return con.playBtn.currentFrameLabel;
        }

        public function resetPlayStatus():void
        {
            con.playBtn.gotoAndStop("play");
        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------------

        public function set buttonStatus(s:Boolean):void
        {
            _buttonStatus = s;
            playButtonStatus();
        }

        public function playButtonStatus():void
        {
            if (_buttonStatus == true)
            {
                con.playBtn.buttonMode = true;
                con.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClick);
                con.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playOver);
                con.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, playOut);

                con.soundBtn.buttonMode = true;
                con.soundBtn.mouseEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                con.playBtn.buttonMode = false;
                con.playBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClick);
                con.playBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playOver);
                con.playBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, playOut);

                con.soundBtn.buttonMode = false;
                con.soundBtn.mouseEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Class that cause the extra loop on mouseevent function

```
 package classes
{
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.media.SoundTransform;
    import flash.media.SoundMixer;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;


    import classes.Playing;
    import classes.progressBar;
    import classes.controlMenu;
    import classes.viewType;
    import classes.downloadVideo;
    import classes.playList;
    import classes.playVideo;

    public class playVideo extends MovieClip
    {
        private var Play:Playing = new Playing();
        private var progressB:progressBar = new progressBar();
        private var conM:controlMenu;
        private var viewT:viewType=new viewType();
        private var downloadV:downloadVideo;
        private var list:playList;
        private var vBox:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private static var ns:NetStream;
        private const buffer:Number = 2;
        private static var videoURL:String;
        private static var vid:Video = new Video();

        private static var meta:Object = new Object();
        private var durationSecs:Number;
        private var durationMins:Number;
        private var durSecsDisplay:String;
        private var durMinsDisplay:String;
        private static var videoDuration:String;

        private static var t:Timer = new Timer(100);

        private static var videoSound:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();

        private var arial:Arial = new Arial();
        private static var durationTxt:TextField=new TextField();
        private var durationTxtF:TextFormat=new TextFormat();

        private var scrubForward:Boolean;
        private static var currentStatus;

        private static var nsArray:Array= new Array();
        private var dummyArray:Array = new Array();


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private var videoLoader:URLLoader;

        public function playVideo()
        {
        }

        public function set newVideo(v:String):void
        {
            currentStatus = "play";
            videoURL = v;

            if (viewT.viewIn == "stream")
            {
                addVideo();
            }
            else if (viewT.viewIn=="download")
            {
                for (var i:uint=0; i<nsArray.length; i++)
                {
                    if (nsArray[i] != null)
                    {
                        nsArray[i].close();
                    }
                }
                videoProperties();
                soundF();
            }
            conM.resetPlayStatus();
        }

        public function videoFunction():void
        {
            vBox.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            vBox.graphics.drawRect(0,36,668,410);
            vBox.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(vBox);

            // Add the instance of vid to the stage
            vid.width = vid.width * 2;
            vid.height = vid.height * 1.5;
            vid.x = vBox.width / 2 - vid.width / 2;
            vid.y = vBox.height / 2 - vid.height / 2 + 36;
            vBox.addChild(vid);

            if (viewT.viewIn == "stream")
            {
                videoProperties();
            }

            soundF();
            durationText();
        }

        public function videoProperties():void
        {
            nc=new NetConnection();

            // Assign variable name for Net Connection 
            nc.connect(null);

            // Assign Var for the NetStream Object using NetConnection
            ns = new NetStream(nc);

            // Add the buffer time to the video Net Stream
            ns.bufferTime = buffer;

            // Set client for Meta Data Function
            ns.client = {};
            ns.client.onMetaData = onMetaData;

            // Attach netStream to our new Video Object
            if (viewT.viewIn == "stream")
            {
                vid.attachNetStream(ns);
            }
            else if (viewT.viewIn == "download")
            {
                nsArray[list.currentIndex - 1] = ns;
                dummyArray.push(ns);
                vid.attachNetStream(ns);
            }

            addVideo();
        }

        private function addVideo():void
        {
            // Assign NetStream to start play automatically by default
            if (viewT.viewIn == "stream" && videoURL == null)
            {
                videoURL = "video/video1.flv";
            }

            ns.play(videoURL);

            conM= new controlMenu();
            conM.buttonStatus = true;
            progressB.progressBarStatus();

            // Add Error listener and listeners for all of our buttons
            ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR,asyncErrorHandler);

            currentStatus = "play";

            t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTick);
            t.start();
        }

        private function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void
        {
            // Do whatever you want if an error arises
        }

        private function onMetaData(info:Object):void
        {
            meta = info;
            /*for (meta in info)
            {
            trace(meta + ":" + info[meta]);
            }*/

            durationSecs = Math.floor(meta.duration);
            durationMins = Math.floor(durationSecs / 60);
            durationMins %=  60;
            durationSecs %=  60;

            if (durationMins < 10)
            {
                durMinsDisplay = "0" + durationMins;
            }
            else
            {
                durMinsDisplay = "" + durationMins;
            }

            if (durationSecs < 10)
            {
                durSecsDisplay = "0" + durationSecs;
            }
            else
            {
                durSecsDisplay = "" + durationSecs;
            }

            videoDuration = durMinsDisplay + ":" + durSecsDisplay;
            Play.vDuration = videoDuration;
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public function prepareArray():void
        {
            list = new playList();

            for (var i:uint=0; i<list.vDataLength; i++)
            {
                nsArray.push(null);
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private function onTick(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            if (viewT.viewIn == "stream" || ns.bytesLoaded == ns.bytesTotal)
            {
                var nsSecs:Number = Math.floor(ns.time);
                var nsMins:Number = Math.floor(nsSecs / 60);

                nsMins %=  60;
                nsSecs %=  60;

                var nsSecsDisplay:String = "";
                var nsMinsDisplay:String = "";
                if (nsMins < 10)
                {
                    nsMinsDisplay = "0" + nsMins;
                }
                else
                {
                    nsMinsDisplay = "" + nsMins;
                }
                if (nsSecs < 10)
                {
                    nsSecsDisplay = "0" + nsSecs;
                }
                else
                {
                    nsSecsDisplay = "" + nsSecs;
                }

                durationTxt.text = nsMinsDisplay + ":" + nsSecsDisplay;
                progressB.progressing = ns.time / meta.duration * 668;
            }
            else if (viewT.viewIn=="download" && ns.bytesLoaded!=ns.bytesTotal)
            {
                list.preloadFlv();
            }

            if (durationTxt.text == videoDuration)
            {
                currentStatus = "end";
                t.stop();
                t.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTick);
                ns.pause();
                ns.seek(0);
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private function soundF():void
        {
            var soundAmount:Number = 7;
            if (viewT.viewIn == "stream")
            {
                ns.soundTransform = videoSound;
                videoSound.volume = soundAmount / 10;
                conM.adjustSoundBtnPos = soundAmount * 10;
            }
            else if (viewT.viewIn=="download")
            {
                if (dummyArray.length == 1 && ns != null)
                {
                    ns.soundTransform = videoSound;
                    videoSound.volume = soundAmount / 10;
                    conM.adjustSoundBtnPos = soundAmount * 10;
                }
                else if (dummyArray.length> 1 && ns!=null)
                {
                    ns.soundTransform = videoSound;
                }
            }
        }

        public function set adjustSound(s:Number):void
        {
            videoSound.volume = s / 100;
            ns.soundTransform = videoSound;
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private function durationText():void
        {
            durationTxtF = new TextFormat();
            durationTxtF.size = 12;
            durationTxtF.leftMargin = 5;
            durationTxtF.font = arial.fontName;

            durationTxt.defaultTextFormat = durationTxtF;
            durationTxt.selectable = false;
            durationTxt.textColor = 0x999999;
            durationTxt.width = 50;
            durationTxt.height = 22;
            durationTxt.x = 476;
            durationTxt.y = 477;
            durationTxt.text = "00:00";
            addChild(durationTxt);
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public function get Duration():String
        {
            return videoDuration;
        }

        public function playStatus():void
        {
            conM=new controlMenu();
            if (conM.currentStatus == "play")
            {
                ns.resume();
                updateProgress();
            }

            if (currentStatus == "pause")
            {
                currentStatus = "play";
                t.start();
            }
        }

        public function pauseStatus():void
        {
            ns.pause();
            t.stop();
            trace("pause");
            if (currentStatus == "play")
            {
                currentStatus = "pause";
            }
        }

        public function get currentVideoStatus():String
        {
            return currentStatus;
        }

        public function restartVideo():void
        {
            ns.resume();
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public function updateProgress():void
        {
            ns.seek((progressB.currentProgress / 668) *meta.duration);
        }

        public function get nsBytesTotal():Number
        {
            return ns.bytesTotal;
        }

        public function get nsBytesLoaded():Number
        {
            return ns.bytesLoaded;
        }

        public function get getVideoURL():String
        {
            return videoURL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly, strongly recommend against doing some sort of flag or timer hack to get around an unexplained behavior - that leads to code bloat and down the line it'll cause you more problems in the long run.

It's much, much, much better to understand why it's calling your function twice. Invest the time in figuring that out (do you have listeners set on multiple display objects? Is this some sort of bubbling issue? Could it be your mouse? Try a clean flash project with just a handler and see if that calls twice, etc), and not only will your code be better and faster but you'll also learn a lot in the process.

Comment: I totally agree with this too.

Comment: I've tried that. Check and recheck, but I still don't know how the hell it manage to run twice. The only possible I could think of that cause the problem might be there's this 2 custom classes(include this 1) that communicate with each other. But even when I use like exp: var me:MEfunction = new MEfunction() from the other custom classes, but I have the first public function of MEfunction (whis is where the mouseEvent buttons are) leave blank. So it shouldn't return anything directly from the MEfunction.

Comment: Can you update your question above to include the code? Is it long? Easier to diagnose that way.

Comment: The codes is kinda long for both classes, cause they does quite a lot of things. The problem I think is not the classes that contains the mouseEvent, but the other classes. There's array involved in it, and I noticed the more object I placed in that array, the more time the mouseevent function fired.

Comment: [Previous comment removed] Nevermind, looking at your code now - just saw you posted it. Stand by...

Comment: Specifically, what behavior is repeating? I see that in your ControlMenu class you're adding a mouseUp listener to the stage - and then I see in your other class that you're creating multiple ControlMenus. Could that have something to do with it? Which array are you adding stuff too that causes more loops?

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I've found out what have cause the problem. I've recheck and recheck, and finally i mange to find out whats the problem. I've remove some function() that contains the addEventListener when I create a new video, thus making it have multiple eventlistener on a single button. But why can 1 button contains multiple same MouseEvent?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a variable so it only runs once. Something like...

```
var runOnce:Boolean = false;

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testEvent);

function testEvent(e:Event):void{
if(runOnce == false){
//do stuff here
runOnce = true;
}
```

It's a bit lazy, but you get the idea.